# How can I just display only title, byline, section and abstract for each from API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch-api

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>NYT API</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nyt.css">
    <script defer src="js/nyt.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <header>
            <h1>Top New York Times HeadLines</h1>
            <h3>This is CTEC 126 Weekly Assignment</h3>
            <label for="section">Select a Section</label>
            <select name="section" id="section">
                <option value="home">Home</option>
                <option value="arts">Art</option>
            </select>
            <button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
            <div id="stories"></div>
        </header>
    </section>
    <script>
        const stories = document.querySelector('#stories')

        function callAPI() {     fetch(`http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/${section.value}.json?api-key=ue5gpNuOXmVwacpftV5uEmjyTFwYmM4i`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    let output = ''
                    console.log(data)
                })
        }

        function displayStories(data) {
            data.results.forEach(item => {
                output += `<h1>${(item.title)}</h1>`
                output += `<div>${(data.byline)}</div>`
                output += `<div>${(data.section)}</div>`
                output += `<div>${(data.abstract)}</div>`
                output += `</div>`
                stories.style.display = output
                stories.innerHTML = output
            })
        }

        const section = document.querySelector('#section')
        const refreshBtn = document.querySelector('#refresh')

        section.addEventListener('change', () => {
            callAPI()
        })

        refreshBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert('Refreshing')
            callAPI()
        })

        callAPI()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code that I already wrote! It still works well in the console web browser, But my purpose to display title, byline, section, and abstract on the page!

I think my code was wrong, Could anyone help me out?

Comment: You are not calling displayStories so it's functionality will not be executed. Try calling this function it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two mistakes - updated code below this will help you out

```
function callAPI() {
    fetch(
      `http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/${section.value}.json?api-key=ue5gpNuOXmVwacpftV5uEmjyTFwYmM4i`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        let output = '';
        console.log(data);
        displayStories(data); // new code, function wasn't called.
      });
  }

  function displayStories(data) {
    let output = ''; // new code there was no output variable, which might cause error in strict mode.
    data.results.forEach((item) => {
      output += `<h1>${item.title}</h1>`;
      output += `<div>${item.byline}</div>`; // updated as data don\'t have byline property
      output += `<div>${item.section}</div>`; // updated as data don\'t have section
      output += `<div>${item.abstract}</div>`; // updated as data don\'t have abstract
      output += `</div>`;
      stories.style.display = output;
      stories.innerHTML = output;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in your code;

- you are not calling `displayStories` inside the `fetch().then()` block, so that function never gets the results to display.
- you do not initialize `output` inside `displayStories` so the code will throw an error when you call that function
- inside the `forEach` loop in `displayStories` you are calling `data` to get individual result property, but the individual results you are looping through are in `item`

Once you change all that, the code works fine.

```js
const stories = document.querySelector('#stories')

function callAPI() {
  fetch(`http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/${section.value}.json?api-key=ue5gpNuOXmVwacpftV5uEmjyTFwYmM4i`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      let output = ''
      displayStories(data)
    })
}

function displayStories(data) {
  let output = ''
  data.results.forEach(item => {
    output += '<section>'
    output += `<a href="${item.url}"><h1>${item.title}</h1></a>`
    output += `<div>${(item.byline)}</div>`
    output += `<div>${(item.section)}</div>`
    output += `<div>${(item.abstract)}</div>`
    output += `</div>`
    output += '</section>'
    stories.innerHTML = output
  })
}

const section = document.querySelector('#section')
const refreshBtn = document.querySelector('#refresh')

section.addEventListener('change', () => {
  callAPI()
})

refreshBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  stories.innerHTML = '<div class="lds-ring"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>';
  callAPI()
})

callAPI()
```

```css
#stories section {
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #333;
}

#stories section a h1 {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

#stories section a {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.lds-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.lds-ring div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 8px solid #888;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ring 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
  border-color: #888 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.lds-ring div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.45s;
}

.lds-ring div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}

.lds-ring div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.15s;
}

@keyframes lds-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>NYT API</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nyt.css">
  <script defer src="js/nyt.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <header>
      <h1>Top New York Times HeadLines</h1>
      <h3>This is CTEC 126 Weekly Assignment</h3>
      <label for="section">Select a Section</label>
      <select name="section" id="section">
        <option value="home">Home</option>
        <option value="arts">Art</option>
      </select>
      <button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
      <div id="stories">
        <div class="lds-ring"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That was helpful for me. Thank you a lot! Could I have one more question that could I display each information in each Square! each line 4-5 column.

Comment: @Jay if you found the answer useful and it solved your original question, please don't forget to mark it as accepted and/or up vote it, have a look at the [ask] section if not clear. Now, I am not sure exactly what you mean by "in each square" could you explain a bit more? Though it sounds that what you are asking is not directly related, and it would be better to ask a new question. If you mean split the information into columns, there are lots of examples out there `width: 20%` on the element would do it.